# How to find out, which SSH client Git is currently using?

Tags: git, ssh

When installing Git (at least on Windows), the user can choose the SSH client Git should use:

[image]

**How to find out later, which one is using?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the open ssh its the recommended one.

Dont use putty unless you know what you do.

Once you set it up you can define/create your keys and git will automatically load them form the `.ssh` folder under your home folder.

---

#### How to check if ssh is installed correctly?

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

and you should see the PID number of the agent if its started.